# Vagrant fork() function is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError) on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, vagrant

Windows 10.

When run `vagrant up`, got these errors:

```
==> centos: Destroying VM and associated drives...
C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/daemons-1.2.4/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:10:in `fork': fork() function is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/daemons-1.2.4/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:10:in `safefork'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/daemons-1.2.4/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:45:in `call_as_daemon'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/daemons-1.2.4/lib/daemons/application.rb:270:in `start_proc'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/daemons-1.2.4/lib/daemons/application.rb:296:in `start'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/daemons-1.2.4/lib/daemons/controller.rb:56:in `run'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/daemons-1.2.4/lib/daemons.rb:197:in `block in run_proc'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/daemons-1.2.4/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:92:in `call'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/daemons-1.2.4/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:92:in `catch_exceptions'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/daemons-1.2.4/lib/daemons.rb:196:in `run_proc'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-dns-1.1.0/lib/vagrant-dns/service.rb:26:in `run!'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-dns-1.1.0/lib/vagrant-dns/service.rb:17:in `start!'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-dns-1.1.0/lib/vagrant-dns/service.rb:52:in `restart!'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-dns-1.1.0/lib/vagrant-dns/restart_middleware.rb:14:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_guest_additions.rb:49:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.13.0/lib/vagrant-vbguest/middleware.rb:31:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Users/hi/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-proxyconf-1.5.2/lib/vagrant-proxyconf/action/only_once.rb:33:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/wait_for_communicator.rb:71:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
```

I have tried to find some solution from GitHub issues:
https://github.com/vagrant-landrush/landrush/issues/16

Got no idea.

Also tried to install this:

```
gem install win32-process
```

The same result.

So I don't know the real problem.

Comment: I'm a little confused, are you trying to run this code from windows? Because I'm pretty sure that `fork` doesn't work on windows which is why you're getting this error.

Comment: @Thermatix So the vagrant can't work well on Windows?

Comment: No, it should be fine as I used it before on windows, you might have to just configure it differently.

Comment: @Thermatix I don't remember have config something. Just don't know how to fix now.

Comment: I see you have the `vagrant-dns` plugin installed, some others have reported that uninstalling it solved the problem.

Comment: @Thermatix You are right! I installed it. After I uninstalled it, it works! Can you write it down as a answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It has been reported that the vagrant-dns plugin can cause this issue on Windows. If it is installed, try uninstalling it.

If that isn't an option, Windows 10 has the Windows Subsystem for Linux feature that you can install. This will allow you to leverage one of the Unix Distro apps in the Windows store to install a bash shell. This will allow you to run your app in a Linux environment, effectively enabling Fork()